# How to get text from an element with other children using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have something similar to the following:

```
<div>
     Hello World
     <div>Something Else</div>
</div>
```

I want to use javascript/jQuery to get just the 'Hello World' text.
I could just wrap it in a span and select that, but I now want to know how to do this.

I thought simply using $('div').text() would work, but it gives me "Hello WorldSomething Else".

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].firstChild;
var text = div.textContent ? div.textContent.trim() : div.innerText;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6VzS/3/)

<sub>Please note that IE8 and earlier versions don't support the `trim` function, if you are using jQuery you can use the jQuery `$.trim()` utility function which is cross-browser. `$.trim(text)`</sub>

Comment: Note that `textContent` is not supported by IE8 and earlier.

Comment: Also, it might not be right to trim the result. The correct text content will include leading whitespace. (For example, in the case of `white-space: pre`. jQuery does it the same way.)

Comment: @minitech good points, thanks, `trim()` can be deleted, IE8 and earlier do not support this function.

Comment: Also the first part of the ternary operation won't work if there is no textContent - `""` is falsy and firefox doesn't support `innerText` so you'll get back `undefined`.  Probably go with `hasOwnProperty` or `in`.

Comment: @Dennis You are correct, it can be modified for different possibilities, but it's supposed that firstChild's text is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

`text()`, as you've discovered, gets the text not only of the targeted node(s) but also of any child/descendant nodes.

Even if this wasn't the case, your code in its current form would still return a concatenation of both pieces of text because your selector targets simply `div`, so jQuery will go find all `div`s and get their text, as one chunk of text.

You can get an element's immediate text only with something like this, though there are other ways.

```
//make a mini plugin for getting the immediate text of an element
$.fn.extend({
    immediateText: function() {
        return this.clone().find("*").remove().end().text();
    }
});

//use the plugin
var immediateText = $('#some_element').immediateText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is too similar to @minitech's answer:

```
var text = $('div:first')
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return (this.nodeType === 3);
    }).text();

alert(text);​
```

You can use a combination of `contents()` (gets the contents of the selected elements) and `filter()` to reduce the matched set to text only (`nodetype === 3` means 'Text').

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxNa/2/)

Of course, you could use `first()` instead if you were confident about how your html was going to look:

```
var text = $('div:first')
    .contents()
    .first()
    .text();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxNa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents):

```
yourDiv.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).map(function() {
    return this.nodeValue;
}).get().join('');
```

Alternatively, sans jQuery:

```
var i, c, result = '';

for(i = 0; c = yourDiv.childNodes[i]; i++) {
    if(c.nodeType === 3) {
        result += c.nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clone the element (the first div), remove all children and get the text, optionally remove whitespace with `$.trim()` :

```
var elm = $('div:first').clone();
var text = $.trim(elm.children().remove().end().text());
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eEeYb/1/)